# The memory address of the fifth element of an array can be calculated by the formula?

Tags: arrays, list, memory, memory-address

The memory address of the fifth element of an array can be calculated by the formula

Answer (score 1):

LOC(Array[5]=Base(Array)+w(5-lower bound), where w is the number of words per memory cell for the
array.